# Android: How can I get the transparent region in an image

Tags: android

How can I get the transparent region in an image in android?

My problem is that I have images with transparent areas and I need to let the user click on regions and handle the click event only when they clicked on the actual colored regions of the image. How can I do this in android?

I saw that Drawable Has a getTrasnsparentRegion method but the default implementation returns null. So I need to overwrite it and put this implementation there.

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you used a bitmap you could then call getPixel(x,y) using the coodinate information provided from the click. I think getPixel returns an argb color value, you could then use this to see if that pixel is transparent.

Comment: this looks helpful. Thank you. I will try to go this route and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is a web api where you can send it an image and it will clear out white space, maybe picnik.

I know android apps can use each other, maybe find an app that can make white space transparent, though I doubt there is one with magic wand like capabilities. I know you would need to get at the developer of the app.

Comment: I was trying to find out how to do that programatically in android. Thank you though for trying to help.